# How do I check whether a webserver send gzip compressed websocket messages or not

Tags: tomcat, websocket, flutter-web

I am currently playing with flutter web and websockets.

As a backend I am using an Apache Tomcat webserver that supports RFC 6455 websockets.

Now, when I run my flutter web app in chrome I initialize a websocket connection to my Tomcat running on localhost.

In the debug console of chrome I get the following two outputs.

First the `Headers` section :

[image]

And in the `Messages`:

[image]

As you can see, the request headers tell Tomcat that the browser accepts gzip.

However, where can I see that the messages `Hello Echo!` were actually compressed?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it is actually pretty easy to check this.

You should not use Chrome but instead use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). It also does not matter whether you use flutter or any other kind of dev platform.

Make sure to read from the correct device (i.e. `Wi-Fi: en0` or `Loopback: lo0` the internal device) and then once network traffic capturing has started use the text input of wireshark above to filter only websocket traffic. To do so enter `(websocket)`.

Now you can see the websocket communication frame by frame with the websocket server and if you click on a frame you can down below in the details uncollapse.

There should be a field saying `Per-Message Compressed: True`.

[image: websocket compression checked with wireshark]

If compression is deactivated (must be toggled on the web server) then it is set to false.

Comment: What if the server under test uses an encrypted connection?

Comment: You can run a proxy locally on your computer to get clear text traffic. And you have to add this proxy to your chrome proxy settings. I use this one here to do that: https://mitmproxy.org/ 

A wonderful tool!